# Draw a semi oval like shape in android

Tags: java, android, canvas

Im trying to draw an arc in android, between two textView using drawArc. My requirement is to achieve an arc as shown in the image [image: ExpectedArc] which is correct arc shape. 
But when i tried ,i'm not getting an perfect arc shape and i got the arc which is of semi ovalshaped[image: ActualArc].

Here is my code snippet:

```
public class ArcView extends View {

    final RectF oval = new RectF();
    Path myPath = new Path();
    Paint paint;
    float left, top, right, bottom;

    public FlightStatusArcView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public FlightStatusArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }
    public FlightStatusArcView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)     {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet set) {
        if (set == null)
            return;
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    public void setArcProperties(float l, float t, float r, float b) {
        left = l;
        top = t;
        right = r;
        bottom = b;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        oval.set(left, top, right, bottom);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

        canvas.drawArc(oval, 180f, 180f, false, paint);
        drawArrow(canvas);
    }



    private void drawArrow(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save();

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setStrokeWidth(4f);

        float startX = oval.left + 20;
        float startY = oval.top + (oval.centerY() - oval.top)/ 2;

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(startX, startY-20);
        path.lineTo(startX + 20, startY + 20);
        path.lineTo(startX + 30, startY -17);
        path.close();
        canvas.drawPath(path, p);
        canvas.restore();
    }


}
```

Please help how to achieve the perfect arc shape using the canvas apis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Path` together with `quadTo` or `cubicTo` to draw a curve like this. This will allow you to draw quadratic or cubic bezier curves. For instance, a cubic bezier curve with two identical control points `(x2, y2)` is constructed like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);

    Path p = new Path();

    float x1 = 100;
    float y1 = 256;

    float x2 = 400;
    float y2 = 32;

    float x3 = 700;
    float y3 = 256;

    p.moveTo(x1, y1);

    p.cubicTo(x2, y2, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
    drawArrow(canvas);
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

You can find more information on `cubicTo` and `quadTo` in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path#cubicTo(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float))

Comment: Thanks. I have achieved the same using quadTo.